# Bootstrap form inline not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add this simple search form while applying form inline class so that controls appear next to each other, but I get the controls displayed above each other and the search bottom in white and looking strange, so can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
                <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="post">
                    Search<input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="input-small" placeholder="Search...">
                    <select id="searchon" name="searchon">
                        <option value="0">First Name</option>
                        <option value="1">Last Name</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                </form>       
          </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap 2 or 3?

Comment: Its 3.. you can see class name like "col-md-8".

Comment: bootstrap latest (just downloaded yesterday) so I believe 3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Bootstrap reference, [**for inline forms** :](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

> This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px
>   wide.

and as far as your layout is concerned,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
                <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="post">
                    Search<input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="input-small" placeholder="Search...">
                    <select id="searchon" name="searchon">
                        <option value="0">First Name</option>
                        <option value="1">Last Name</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                </form>       
          </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

its perfectly fine..inline :

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/reb5C/)

Comment: this is very strange, could it be browser issue?! But I tested it on Chrome, Firefox also on Windows and linux machine and I get same result :( any possible reason you think could lead to this strange behaviour?

Comment: @MChan : please check the fiddle in all browsers you have, and then comment back here if problem persists..i don't think its a browser issues because BS is cross-browser!!

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue with `form-inline`. For me `input-group` within `form-inline` worked to keep following input and button in a row next to each other instead of one on top of the other.

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked for me too

Comment: This works, but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary. It's been 2 years, I'm on Bootstrap 5.3.2 and this is still an issue. form-inline should be inline

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a code snippet from bootstrap. I found that the 2 classes 'control-group' and 'controls' broke the inline. removing the 2 classes fixed it for me.

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Name">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
```

to:

```
            <label class="control-label" for="Name">Name</label>

                <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
```

Comment: But when you remove the from-control class, you have lost the styling for the input control. What's your solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! removing the second class from the div worked for me.

```
<form class="form-inline name=" search">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="rego" id="search_box" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="6" type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="PLATE NO">
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" value="  Programe Tag  " />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

to

```
<form class="form-inline name=" search">
<fieldset>
    <input name="rego" id="search_box" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="6" type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="PLATE NO">
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" value="  Programe Tag  " />
</fieldset>
```